# Azure Functions V2 Deserialize HttpRequest as object

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm surprised I can't find the answer to this but I've got an Azure function (HTTP Trigger) I simply want to deserialize the content as an object. Previously with V1 I was able to do this,

**Functions V1**

```
[FunctionName("RequestFunction")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    // Successful deserialization of the content
    var accountEvent = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<AccountEventDTO>();

    // Rest of the function...
}
```

But now with V2 it looks more like this,

**Functions V2**

```
[FunctionName("RequestFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    // Content doesn't exist on HttpRequest anymore so this line doesn't compile
    var accountEvent = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<AccountEventDTO>();

    // Rest of the function...
}
```

I can get the body to access the stream from the HttpRequest object but am unsure how I would cast that to the expected object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The API has changed a bit.  As you have seen `Content` does not exist anymore.  However you can still get the same functionality by using the extension method that is included in the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http` namespace (which should be included already as a dependency):

```
string json = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

You can view the source of this extension method [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/cdeb65faacf04c53845fb76c4b513c9998fc97de/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http/Extensions/HttpRequestExtensions.cs)

Then you would use Json.NET to deserialize (Json.NET is already a dependency too)

```
var someModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeModel>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @tokyo0709 it’s funny because I just had to figure this out yesterday!

Comment: Haha nice well that works out. You wouldn't happen to know how to code the receiver from a queue/topic as input in a function to get the strongly typed object back out would you from the Message object?

Comment: @tokyo0709 If I am understanding correctly, I think you have to to deserialize the string in the function itself.  There could be ways around that potentially but I always just deserialize in the function before passing it to dependent libraries

Comment: Gotcha so you would pull the body out as a string just like this example and follow same process to deserialize?

Comment: @tokyo0709 so if you are doing a queue trigger function, the default parameter _is_ a string so you just take that parameter and deserialize.  As far as I know the queue triggers only deal with strings

Comment: Just tested that. You were right again. Thanks again much appreciated. Would give you 1000 internet points if I could.

Comment: --11 unfortunately this isnt working in v2 anymore, im getting `static types cannot be used as type arguments`

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' it sounds like you have a different problem. That error message means whatever class you are using as the `T` parameter in `DeserializeObject<T>()` is `static` (i.e cannot be instantiated). See here for more details. You might want to remove the downvote too because it might signal to future users that this answer is incorrect, when in fact it was an error with your code

Comment: you are totally correct, sorry about that, can you make 1 character change to your answer so that i can update it back up? i figured the azure function runtime changed again and made old code obsolete

Answer (score 16):

You can bind to a custom object instead of HttpRequest. This object is created from the body of the request and parsed as JSON. Similarly, a type can be passed to the HTTP response output binding and returned as the response body, along with a 200 status code.
Example:

```
public static partial class SayHelloFunction
{
    [FunctionName("SayHello")]
    public static async Task<ActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]Person person, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        return person.Name != null ?
                (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {person.Name}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass an instance of Person.");
    }
}
```

The model to bind to..

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> The HTTP request: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/SayHello Body:  {
>     name: "Foo" }

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the type of your Object, you can do:

```
string json = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even bind to `JObject` directly:

```
    [FunctionName("JsonEcho")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
       [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]JObject json,
       ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Received some JSON: {json}");

        return new OkObjectResult(json)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
  {
       var person = await req.ReadFromJsonAsync<Person>();

  }
```